# PYPDFTK Error 32

Tags: python, pdf

I am back at coding above my head again in producing a program that will automatically fill out some Partner PDF's with our employees information.  Currently, we have a process that involves over a 40 page PDF which we have filling in automatically with information after you make it through the first couple pages.

What we are looking for is creating a UI that allows the employee to type their info once, then have it pumped through the 40 pages filling in all the key form spots, then break the PDF up appropriately and file to the correct folders for compliance.

90% of this I have experience coding from the UI, to splitting up a completed file, but my problem is working with the PDF to fill in forms.  I have exerpience using items such as PDFMiner and PDFQuery to scrape a PDF but I am stuck on entering it.

I am currently attempting to use PyPDFTK but when setting it up via their example, I can't even clear the first step as the temp file it looks like the code is trying to access is not accessible, see example basic code:

```
import pypdftk
datas = {
'firstname': 'Julien',
'company': 'revolunet',
'price': 42
}
generated_pdf = pypdftk.fill_form('main.pdf', datas)
```

And it keeps producing an error 32 and I can't figure out why!?  Is this the best option and if so how can I try and remedy this.

Thank you,

Andy.

Answer (score 0):

pypdftk author here; can you please paste the traceback ?

Generally this means the pdftk binary was not found and you can change it with the `PDFTK_PATH` environment variable. see https://github.com/revolunet/pypdftk/blob/master/README.md#pdftk-path